# Download Azure Diagnostics Logs using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-diagnostics

I have enabled Diagnostics Logs for my azure VMs and Web Apps. 
How can download these diagnostics logs using powershell. 
Is powershell does n't have any cmdlet then could you suggest any other scripting language using i can download these logs.

Answer (score 0):

Diagnostics uses Azure Storage to store the data, so you should use any Azure Storage (Blob, Table) CMDlets to get the logs.

Could be useful :

- [Using Azure PowerShell with Azure Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-powershell-guide-full/)
- [How to import/export data with Excel to/from Azure table storage](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-importexport-data-9458fa47)
- [Store and view diagnostic data in Azure Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics-storage/)